# From scatter plot to 2D numpy array with binary entries in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scatter-plot, binary-matrix

I have two numpy array 'x' and 'y'. I get this scatter plot using 'matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y)'.

[image]

Now, how can I get a matrix with binary values (1,0) that matches the scatter plot?

The matrix should be constructed as follows: if circle then 1 else 0

Comment: Could you better explain `if circle then 1 else 0`?

Comment: I mean a matrix that has value 1 at the coordinates where we see the dots. As if it were an image but instead of having value between 0 and 255 I only need 0 and 1 depending on the presence of the dot

Comment: What you want is a 2D histogram. Have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.